# Equivalence of power series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Ok, this is probably a very silly question, and I'm probably overcomplicating the issue, but here it goes:

I'm making questions on power series, and it asks me to find the convergence radius of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}$$

Of course, usually a power series is given in the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$$

and we see that we here have to take $$a_n = \begin{cases}1 \quad n = k! 
 \quad \mathrm{for \ some \ k}\\ 0 \quad \mathrm{else}\end{cases}$$

From this, it is easy to see that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = 1$ as we have a subsequence converging to $1$ and the limsup can't become greater than that, so $1$ is the largest limit of a subsequence. Hence, the convergence radius is $1$.

**My concern**: Shouldn't we formally show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$$

for my choice of $(a_n)_n$? In the left sum, we sum over 'less' terms that the right one, while in the right sum we sum over 'more' terms, but these are zero so intuitively the terms are not affected.

Write $(c_n)_n$ for the left partial sums and $(d_n)_n$ for the right partial sums. Then we see that $(d_n)_n$ has the form $(c_1,\underbrace{c_1, \dots, c_1}_{k_1 terms}, c_2, \underbrace{c_2, \dots, c_2}_{k_2 terms}, \dots)$ and it suffices to show that

> $(c_n)_n$ converges if and only if $(d_n)_n$ converges and in this
>   case the limits coincide

If $(d_n)_n$ converges, then $(c_n)_n$ converges to the same limit because it contains $(c_n)_n$ as a subsequence.

Conversely, assume $(c_n)_n$ converges to $c$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $n_0$ such that $d(c_n, c) < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq n_0$. If $n \geq n_0 + k_1 + \dots + k_{n_0}$, then $d_n\in \{c_{n_0}, c_{n_0+1}, \dots\}$ and it follows that $d(d_n, c) < \epsilon$. Hence $d_n \to c$, proving the statement. $\quad \square$.

Any thoughts about it? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: There is a unique way to express something as a power series, so you don't need to worry about rearrangements changing the series. Accordingly, your proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to formally show it. The $a_n$ are exactly as you said. We just take a limsup of a very "sparse" sequence (most terms are $0$) to determine the radius of convergence. The argument about there being a constant subsequence of $1$'s and thus the same holds for the root-sequence, is correct.

Comment: Thank you, but writing the power series as $\sum_n z^{n!}$ isn't abuse of notation then? Because what it actually meant is the series $\sum_n a_n z^n$ as I described it. Don't we need to prove that they are equal to justify this abuse of notation?

Comment: @user661541 No, power series are equal iff their coefficients are equal. (true by definition for formal power series, true by theorem for ones with a positive radius of convergence.) The notation $\sum_n z^{n!}$ represents only those powers that happen to be factorials.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see it. Formally, a power series is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. That is, it is the limit of $(\sum_{n=0}^k a_n z^n)_{k=0}^\infty$. The series in the problem statement has other partial sums, so one needs to show that both representations are equal?

Comment: @user661541 It has the same partial sums. The $N$'th partial sum in both cases is just all the sum of all $z^{i!}$ for $i$ with $i! \le N$.

Comment: I disagree. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ has partial sums $(z,z+z^2, z+z^2, z+z^2, z+z^2, z+z^2+z^6,...)$ while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!}$ has partial sums $(z,z+z^2,z+z^2 + z^6, ....)$ and you see one is contained in the other as a subsequence

Comment: @user661541 You're wrong about the second partial sums. You skip terms.

Comment: I am? Then I must have misunderstood something! I learnt that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n!} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^k z^{n!} = \lim_k( z, z+z^2, z+z^2+ z^6, ...)$  and this seems to match with what I wrote.

Comment: @user661541 Anyway, however you define it, the sequences of partial sums have exactly the same limit, as the $a_n z^n$ one only has extra duplicated terms.

Comment: Yes, but this was why I asked my question. If we write $\sum_n z^{n!}$ to represent a power series, we should first formally prove that it represents the power series I wrote down in my question right?

Comment: @user661541 the factorial notation is an "abuse of notation" for a power series. It is by definition the same as the $a_n z^n$ variant you use. No need for a proof, as I said. It's just the correct definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97810/discussion-between-user661541-and-henno-brandsma).